SQL DataAdapter Removes # Character and Concatenates Values (e.g., 10#1000 becomes 101000) When Filling DataSet
I'm using a stored procedure to fetch data in a C# application. The SQL query returns the correct values when executed directly in SQL Server, but when I use a SqlDataAdapter to fill a DataSet, the output values change from 10#1000 to 101000. It seems like the # character is being removed and the values are concatenated. The database table column has values as below:
CancelChargesStep1  | CancelChargesStep2    | CancelChargesStep3
------------------------------------------------------------------
10#1000             | 20#500                | 30#250

Here's a simplified version of my C# code:
`SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure", sqlConn);
sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);`

I’ve tried casting the columns in my SQL query as VARCHAR or NVARCHAR to ensure that the values are treated as strings:
SELECT  CAST(CancelChargesStep1 AS VARCHAR(50)) AS CancelChargesStep1 FROM MyTable;

Please add a Minimal, Reproducible Example in this question.

Show the code which you use to read the column values from your ds DataSet.

What is the defined data type of the column, both in the database and the dataset. The system isn't in the habit of even looking at string contents so I suspect there's some numeric misconfiguration here, when these should presumably be opaque strings. Secondly: why are you using dataset? That is almost never the appropriate solution to any problem that most applications encounter (unless you're reimplementing SSMS or an ad-hoc reporting engine).

I did a  Quick watch (crtl+Alt+Q) once the dataset object is fill.  Also I tried
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
string result = row["CancelChargesStep1"].ToString();
Console.WriteLine(result);
}
But the result is same. @Anand Sowmithiran

I did not find any mistake in your work. I am presenting the solution thoroughly from data definition to data retrieval in SQL Server. Finally the front-end coding in c#.

The data definition of the table will be.

CREATE TABLE TEST1
(CancelChargesStep1 VARCHAR(50), 
CancelChargesStep2 VARCHAR(50), 
CancelChargesStep3 VARCHAR(50));


Then insert data into the table

INSERT INTO Test1(CancelChargesStep1 , CancelChargesStep2 , CancelChargesStep3) 
VALUES
('10#1000','20#500','30#250');


Stored Procedure to fetch Data

CREATE PROCEDURE  DRL_TEST
AS
SELECT CancelChargesStep1 , CancelChargesStep2 , CancelChargesStep3 FROM TEST1
RETURN;

The above three steps has been implemented in SQL Server 2014 Express

I follow your code for c#. No change. Just add the last line to see the result in data grid. You can overlook it.

This c# code has been implemented in .Net Framework 4.7 on VS2022.
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("DRL_TEST", sqlConn);
sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataGrid1.DataSource= ds.Tables[0];

 



Thank you for your reply @Abu Ben Reaz.
My c# code is implemented in .net5.0 on VS2019. I'll try doing it in vs2022
